# How do I find the login id that I used to login in TortoiseSVN?

Tags: windows, svn, tortoisesvn

I can't remember the login id that I used for TortoiseSVN. Where can I find the login id.

I found 'Saved Data' under Settings. But it has only Clear button to clear out the authentication information.

Nowhere else could I find the login ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use up-to-date Subversion client tools and run the `svn auth` command. Alternatively, check the contents of the [`%APPDATA%\Subversion\auth\svn.simple`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.credcache) directory.

If the username is not cached there and you don't see it, contact your manager or the SVN sever administrator.

Comment: Thanks. Could see the username within the svn.simple folder.

Comment: FWIW: On Windows, examining files in `AppData\Roaming\Subversion\auth\svn.simple` (as mentioned) is the only way I could get this.  DETAILS: running TortoiseSVN only brings up message "TortoiseSVN is a shell extension ...". No way to execute there. Running a standard Windows command prompt, gives "svn" is not recognized as a .. command". Using the shell extension, I've looked through all the menu items, and the Settings - no mention of username.